# Pra que serve e como funciona o comando MINUS no oracle

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, oracle, select

Eu nunca vi esse comando antes e também não achei ele por aqui, não sei se ele tem um outro nome e pela documentação da Oracle não deu pra entender exatamente como ele funciona. Só quero uma explicação e um exemplo simples do comando. Muito obrigado.

Gostaria de saber também porque o comando abaixo não funciona ( apartentemente é por causa do b.NOM_CARRO) .

```
SELECT b.COD_CARRO, b.NOM_CARRO FROM CARROS b
MINUS
SELECT a.COD_CARRO FROM VEICULOS a;
```

Comment: Como eu faço então pra retornar o nome do veiculo na ID retornada? Desculpa se essas perguntas forem muito iniciante. Eu não entendi esses exemplos,  e nem as respostas.

Comment: mas ta errado o meu código, eu disse que não funciona. Se eu tirar o  b.NOM_CARRO aí sim ele funciona, mas eu preciso desse nome.

Comment: Agora acho que entendi. Vc poderia ter explicado isso na própria pergunta pois não ficou claro essa situação..

Comment: Desconheço um modo de aplicar um "ignore column" usando o MINUS. Você teria que usar o NOT EXISTS. Adicionei na resposta abaixo.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

O comando MINUS do Oracle tem o sentido de "exceção". É utilizado normalmente para excluir dados que retornem numa consulta. Não confunda com excluir dados como o DELETE. É algo bem diferente.

Tomando o seu código como exemplo,

```
SELECT b.COD_CARRO, b.NOM_CARRO FROM CARROS b
MINUS
SELECT a.COD_CARRO FROM VEICULOS a;
```

Suponha que na tabela "b" exista um registro cujo COD_CARRO é 1.

Caso exista COD_CARRO = 1 na tabela "a", esse registro será excluído do resultado do SELECT.

No caso de selecionar quantidade de colunas diferentes, recomenda-se o uso da função `NOT EXISTS`.

No seu caso ficaria assim:

```
SELECT b.COD_CARRO, b.NOM_CARRO FROM CARROS b
WHERE
NOT EXISTS
(
SELECT 0 FROM a 
WHERE 
a.COD_CARRO = b.COD_CARRO
);
```

Comment: mas esse código não está funcionando. Na documentação pede um argumento, e se eu quiser dois pra poder pegar o nome dos que não estão no segundo resultado?

Comment: Se está funcionando ou não, é indiferente. Apenas entenda a função do MINUS.

Answer (score 3):

Uma forma sucinta é um "menos" , o resultado de uma query menos o da outra.

Exemplo : vendedores que não venderam nada este mês

```
Select codigo 
from vendedores
Minus
Select codigo_vendedor
From vendas
Where to_char(data_venda,'yyyymm') = to_char(sysdate,'yyyymm')
```

Comment: Ele quer selecionar 2 campos na primeira tabela e comparar apenas 1 campo na segunda tabela do "minus". O comando MINUS não permite, por isso, uma solução mais adequada seria usar NOT EXISTS.

Comment: Sim , as colunas do select devem ter o mesmo número e tipos.

Answer (score 1):

Segundo a [documentação](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/queries004.htm) o minus retornar todas as linhas não duplicadas da primeira consulta que não esteja na segunda consulta, é parecido com 'calculo' da diferença na teoria dos conjutos. Em alguns casos pode ser equivalente ao select com `WHERE NOT IN()`.